# censored gee model

Tags: r, repeated-measures, censoring, generalized-estimating-equations, tobit-regression

Does anyone know if it is possible to fit a left censored GEE model with autoregressive correlation structure ?

I know `censReg` can handle left censored repeated data but I am not sure if I can specify a autoregressive correlation structure ?